# My Python OpenCV program is not detecting the whole page but rather a singular rectangle on the page

Tags: python, opencv, imutils

I'm trying to write a program in Python that can mark exam papers using opencv and imutils, I have attached an example. I'm trying to get a top down view of the page but it's not detecting the right contours.[Contours drawn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCo08.jpg) [imutils four_point_transform applied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lOJaS.png) I would like it to apply the function to the whole page and not to the questions. Is it possible to use the corner borders for four_point_transform? It may not be very visible so here is the [original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFFnS.jpg).

```
# Import libraries
import cv2
import numpy as np
import imutils
from imutils import contours
from imutils.perspective import four_point_transform

# Verify exam sheet location
image = cv2.imread("test4.jpg")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), 0)
edge = cv2.Canny(blur, 100, 200)

# Locate contours
contours = cv2.findContours(edge.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
    cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = imutils.grab_contours(contours)
docCnt = None

# Verify main object is exam
if len(contours) > 0:
    contours = sorted(contours, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)
    for c in contours:
        peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
        approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.02 * peri, True)
        if len(approx) == 4:
            docCnt = approx
            break

# Create a top-down view of paper
paper = four_point_transform(image, docCnt.reshape(4,2))
warped = four_point_transform(edge, docCnt.reshape(4,2))

# Draw contours
cv2.drawContours(image, contours, -1, (0,255,0), 3)
cv2.imwrite("Contours.jpg", image)

# Display images
cv2.imshow("Original", image)
# cv2.imshow("Perspective", paper)
# cv2.imshow("Processed", edge)
# cv2.imshow("Processed + Perspective", warped)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please **read** the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: You have not shown your code.  You should just get the EXTERNAL contour, not all contours, in order to rectify the image to face-on view. Then you can detect the internal contours for further processing once the image is rectified to face-on view.

Comment: Filter on the largest contour representing the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The contour just needed a bit of dilating and then it was able to capture the paper in itself. Here is the code:

```
image = cv2.imread('Example.jpg') # read image and convert to rgb for each plotting
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) # turn to gray
blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), 0) # blurring
edges = cv2.Canny(blurred, 50, 150) # edges
kernel = np.ones((5,5), np.uint8) # kernel for dilating
edges = cv2.dilate(edges, kernel, iterations=3) # dilating
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(edges.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE) # get contours
largest_contour = max(contours, key = cv2.contourArea) # get largest
im_cont = image.copy() # copy image for contouring
```

In the above code, I went through a standard canny edge detection. Then, I got the approximation of the contour:

```
hull = cv2.convexHull(largest_contour) # get the hull
epsilon = 0.02 * cv2.arcLength(largest_contour, True) # epsilon
pts1 = np.float32(cv2.approxPolyDP(hull, epsilon, True).reshape(-1, 2)) # get the points
pts2 = np.float32([[0, 0], [image.shape[1], 0], [image.shape[1], image.shape[0]], [0, image.shape[0]]]) # get original edges
matrix = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(pts1, pts2) # get perspective transform matrix
result = cv2.warpPerspective(image, matrix, (image.shape[1], image.shape[0])) # apply matrix to image
```

Plotting, I got the following results:

[image: Transformed]

Maybe think also a bit about stretching to make the aspect ratio a bit better. [This is a nice tutorial as well](https://pyimagesearch.com/2014/08/25/4-point-opencv-getperspective-transform-example/)

**V2.0**:Using imutils

As you can see from the function, all you require for the function are the image itself and the coordinates of the detected corner. Hence, here is the adjusted code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
%matplotlib notebook 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from imutils.perspective import four_point_transform
#####################################################################################################
image = cv2.imread('Example.jpg') # read image and convert to rgb for each plotting
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) # turn to gray
blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), 0) # blurring
edges = cv2.Canny(blurred, 50, 150) # edges
kernel = np.ones((5,5), np.uint8) # kernel for dilating
edges = cv2.dilate(edges, kernel, iterations=3) # dilating
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(edges.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE) # get contours
largest_contour = max(contours, key = cv2.contourArea) # get largest
im_cont = image.copy() # copy image for contouring
cv2.drawContours(im_cont, largest_contour, -1, (255,0,0), 2)
#####################################################################################################
hull = cv2.convexHull(largest_contour) # get the hull
epsilon = 0.02 * cv2.arcLength(largest_contour, True) # epsilon
pts1 = np.float32(cv2.approxPolyDP(hull, epsilon, True).reshape(-1, 2)) # get the points
result = four_point_transform(image, pts1) # using imutils
```

Here is the result, the nice addition is that the imutils function additionally scales the results. [image: Imutils results]

Comment: I'm not too familiar with opencv, could you explain which part allows opencv to detect the largest contours and how I can integrate your solution into my code? (Sorry for not uploading it with the original question)

Comment: it's in the line where i am assigning largest contour.`largest_contour = max(contours, key = cv2.contourArea)`. This translates to "get me the largest contour by area".

Comment: @mranonymous7122 did I answer your question or is there something still unclear?

Comment: It makes sense but I wanted to use imutils four_point_transform because it warps and scales the image on its own correctly but I'm not sure what the function needs. When I try `paper = four_point_transform(image, largest_contour.reshape(0,0))` , I get `ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 13446 into shape (0,0)`. I'm not sure what variable it needs, or is that just something I need to check in the imutils docs?

Comment: I found the code for four_point_transform is [this](https://pastebin.com/WzMBCXgA). I'm unsure on is which contour variable I need in order for it to scale the whole page.

Comment: I noticed in the second image you posted, you located each corner of the paper. Would it be possible for opencv to locate the black corners already on the paper?

Comment: The imutils function is basically also using the cv2 functions that I wrote in the code. I will edit my answer to include the imutils function. As for detecting the black corners, I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: @mranonymous7122 I added the code for using imutils, please remember to close the question if I answered it correctly. Would appreciate it :D

Comment: Your new code worked perfectly, thanks.