# OpenCV: Finding columns in an Arabic journal (Python)

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, ocr

I am new to OpenCV and a rookie Python user. I tried to stitch together code I found online to solve a problem for my research. I have hundreds of pages of an Arabic language journal from 1870 where each page contains two columns within a thick black border. I want to extract the two columns as image files to run OCR on them separately, also ignoring header and footer. Here is an example of a page:

[Page 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6izxt.png)

I have ten pages of the original print as separate png files. I wrote the following script to process each one. It works as intended with 2 of the 10 pages, but fails to produce columns in the other 8. I don't understand all the functions well enough to know where I can play around with the values, or if my entire method is misguided - I figured the best way to learn would be to ask the community how you would tackle the problem.

```
import cv2

def cutpage(fname, pnum):
    image = cv2.imread(fname)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (7,7), 0)
    thresh = cv2.threshold(blur, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
    kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (3, 13))
    dilate = cv2.dilate(thresh, kernel, iterations=1)
    dilatename = "temp/dilate" + str(pnum) + ".png"
    cv2.imwrite(dilatename, dilate)
    cnts = cv2.findContours(dilate, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
    cnts = sorted(cnts, key=lambda x: cv2.boundingRect(x)[0])

    fullpage=1
    column=1
    for c in cnts:
        x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        if h > 300 and w > 20:
            if (h/w)<2.5:
                print("Found full page: ", x, y, w, h)
                filename = "temp/p" + str(pnum) + "-full" + str(fullpage) + ".png"
                fullpage+=1
            else:
                print("Found column: ", x, y, w, h)
                filename = "temp/p" + str(pnum) + "-col" + str(column) + ".png"
                column+=1
            roi = image[y:y+h, x:x+w]
            cv2.imwrite(filename, roi)
    return (column-1)
        
for nr in range(10):
    filename = "p"+str(nr)+".png"
    print("Checking page", nr)
    diditwork = cutpage(filename, nr)
    print("Found", diditwork, "columns")
```

Following a tutorial, I create a blurred and dilated binary inversion, so that it can identify different rectangular fields by large white areas. I also save a copy of each dilated version so I can see what it looks like, here is the page above after processing:

[Page 3 dilated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58qUm.png)

The "for c in cnts" loop is supposed to find large rectangular areas in the image. If the h/w ratio is less than 2.5, I get a full page (without header and footer, this works well), and if the h/w ratio is more than this, I know that it's a column, and it saves this as for example temp/p2-col2.png

I get some nice full pages without the header and footer, that is, with only the larger black border, but without it being cut into columns. In 2 of the 10 pages, I get exactly what I want, which is this:

[Successful column from page 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VTsUN.png)

Since I get the desired result some of the time, something must be working, but I don't know how to refine it further.

EDIT:

Here are more examples of pages:

[P0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHZYQ.png)

[P1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PfsD4.png)

[P5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwmsf.png)

Comment: did you try increasing the dilation? In the page 3 example, the contour has a break on the bottom, you can try to use iterations= 2,3,4...

Comment: I tried to play with the iterations, thanks for the advice! Sometimes 2 works better, sometimes not. I wrote some quick code that does a second run: if it doesn't find 2 columns with dilate 1, it tries with dilate 2. This works for some other pages, but sometimes it finds more than 2 columns - it looks like at higher dilation iterations, it starts finding 3-4 rectangles where I am looking for 2. At 3, it starts finding many thin slices. Not sure where the sweet spot is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried a bit of stuff without any dilation, as I wanted to see if it would be possible to just use the middle line as a "separator". Here is the code:

```
im = cv2.cvtColor(cv2.imread("arabic.png"), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB) # read im as rgb for better plots
gray = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY) # convert to gray
_, threshold = cv2.threshold(gray, 250, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV) # inverse thresholding
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(threshold, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE) # find contours
sortedContours = sorted(contours, key = cv2.contourArea, reverse=True) # sort according to area, descending
bigBox = sortedContours[0] # get the contour of the big box
middleLine = sortedContours[1] # get the contour of the vertical line
xMiddleLine, _, _, _ = cv2.boundingRect(middleLine) # get x coordinate of middleLine
leftBoxContour = np.array([point for point in bigBox if point[0, 0] < xMiddleLine]) # assign left of line as points from the big contour
rightBoxContour = np.array([point for point in bigBox if point[0, 0] >= xMiddleLine]) # assigh right of line as points from the big contour
leftBoxX, leftBoxY, leftBoxW, leftBoxH = cv2.boundingRect(leftBoxContour) # get properties of box on left
rightBoxX, rightBoxY, rightBoxW, rightBoxH = cv2.boundingRect(rightBoxContour) # get properties of box on right
leftBoxCrop = im[leftBoxY:leftBoxY + leftBoxH, leftBoxX:leftBoxX + leftBoxW] # crop left 
rightBoxCrop = im[rightBoxY:rightBoxY + rightBoxH, rightBoxX:rightBoxX + rightBoxW] # crop right
# maybe do you assertations about aspect ratio??
cv2.imwrite("right.png", rightBoxCrop) # save image
cv2.imwrite("left.png", leftBoxCrop) # save image
```

I did not use any assertions about aspect ratio, so maybe this is something you would need to do still..

Basically, the most important lines in this approach are the generation of a left contour and right contour based on the x coordinates. Here is the final result that I got:

[image: Results]

There are still some black parts coming from the edges, but for OCR this should not be a problem.

FYI: I am using the following packages in jupyter:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
%matplotlib notebook
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

**V2.0**: doing it with only the big box detection:

So I did a bit of dilation and the big box was easy enough to detect. I used a horizontal kernel to make sure that the vertical lines of the big box are always thick enough to be detected. I could not however solve the issue of the middle line because it was very thin... Nonetheless, here is the code for the mentioned approach:

```
im = cv2.cvtColor(cv2.imread("1.png"), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB) # read im as rgb for better plots
gray = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY) # convert to gray
gray[gray<255] = 0 # added some contrast to make it either completly black or white
_, threshold = cv2.threshold(gray, 250, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV) # inverse thresholding
thresholdDilated = cv2.dilate(threshold, np.ones((1,10)), iterations = 1) # dilate horizontally
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(thresholdDilated, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE) # find contours
sortedContours = sorted(contours, key = cv2.contourArea, reverse=True) # sort according to area, descending
x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(sortedContours[0]) # get the bounding rect properties of the contour
left = im[y:y+h, x:x+int(w/2)+10].copy() # generate left, I included 10 pix from the right just in case
right = im[y:y+h, int(w/2)-10:w].copy() # and right, I included 10 pix from the left just in case
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows = 2, ncols = 3) # plotting...
ax[0,0].axis("off")
ax[0,1].imshow(im)
ax[0,1].axis("off")
ax[0,2].axis("off")
ax[1,0].imshow(left)
ax[1,0].axis("off")
ax[1,1].axis("off")
ax[1,2].imshow(right)
ax[1,2].axis("off")
```

These are the results, you can notice that it is not perfect, but again, since your goal is OCR, this should not be a problem.

[image: First example]
[image: Second example]
[image: Third example]
[image: Fourth example]

Let me know if this is fine, if not, I'll scratch my head to find a better solution...

**V3.0**: An even better way for a straighter image, which will improve the quality of the OCR.

Inspired by another answer I had here: [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77756968/16815358). It would make sense to straighten the images so that the OCR has a better results. Hence, I used the four point transform on the detected outer box. This will straighten the image a bit and will make the text more horizontal. Here is the code:

```
im = cv2.cvtColor(cv2.imread("2.png"), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB) # read im as rgb for better plots
gray = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY) # convert to gray
gray[gray<255] = 0 # added some contrast to make it either completly black or white
_, threshold = cv2.threshold(gray, 250, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV) # inverse thresholding
thresholdDilated = cv2.dilate(threshold, np.ones((1,10)), iterations = 1) # dilate horizontally
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(thresholdDilated, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE) # find contours
largest_contour = max(contours, key = cv2.contourArea) # get largest contour
hull = cv2.convexHull(largest_contour) # get the hull
epsilon = 0.02 * cv2.arcLength(largest_contour, True) # epsilon
pts1 = np.float32(cv2.approxPolyDP(hull, epsilon, True).reshape(-1, 2)) # get the points
result = four_point_transform(im, pts1) # using imutils
height, width = result.shape[:2] # get the dimensions of the transformed image
left = result[:, 0:int(width/2)].copy() # from the beginning to half the width
right = result[:, int(width/2): width].copy() # from half the width till the end
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows = 2, ncols = 3) # plotting...
ax[0,0].axis("off")
ax[0,1].imshow(result)
ax[0,1].axvline(width/2)
ax[0,1].axis("off")
ax[0,2].axis("off")
ax[1,0].imshow(left)
ax[1,0].axis("off")
ax[1,1].axis("off")
ax[1,2].imshow(right)
ax[1,2].axis("off")
```

With the following packages:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
%matplotlib notebook
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from imutils.perspective import four_point_transform
```

As you can see from the code, this is a much nicer approach, where you kind of force the image to be centered and horizontal, due to the four point transform. Additionally, there is no need to include some overlap, as the images are quite nicely separated. Here is one example for you:

[image: Example with four point transform]

Comment: Thank you so much! This code works very well for the example page I gave you, but with some other pages I tried, it produces columns that are much too thin. The code acts as if the left border of the column IS a column, and draws the middle line where the text begins. Since this is a specific case, maybe there's a way to always establish a middle line that is roughly in the middle of the original image. Is there a way to search through the rectangles identified, and only return those which are half the width of the original image, plus minus 25% say?

Comment: Can you please add some more examples? This way I can maybe add a few lines to pre-process the image. Otherwise, for your second question, yes this is possible. As you can use the width and heights of the boxes generated from the contours.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time! I added three more pages to my original post (furthest down in the post), I can't add more since I'm new to Stackoverflow and it limits the amount of links one can use.

Comment: Sure thing :) I'll check them sometime in the afternoon

Comment: Would it be enough to just do it with detecting the big box and then taking half the distance from the left as the first column and to the right as a second column? I was able to identify the bix box on all images with a bit of dilation, however the thin middle line breaks too often and cannot be dilated without eventually ruining the detection of the big box

Comment: @JonathanJonsson please check my updates

Comment: Thank you so much Tino! I have been sick in bed for a couple of days so I haven't checked StackOverflow, but your v3.0 is doing some real magic - it looks excellent! I will have to look through it line by line to learn exactly what it's doing when I feel better. Meanwhile, if I use this in my research, can I have your full name? I want to give you credit if I end up using the code.

Comment: Sure thing, please send me an email at mehyeddin.derbass@gmail.com

Comment: Also, if this worked for you, remember to close the question. Would appreciate it! Get well soon and ttyl! :D